# Consider the quadratic integer ring $A=\Bbb Z[\sqrt-2]$. Show that $U(A)=\{-1,1\}$.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the quadratic integer ring $A=\Bbb Z[\sqrt-2]$. Show that $U(A)=\{-1,1\}.$

$\bf{Remark:}$ $U(A)$ indicates the set of inversible elements of $A$.

I know that $\alpha = a + b\sqrt{-2}$ is inversible iff $N(\alpha)=a^2+2b^2=1$.

but I don’t know how to go on. Can someone help me?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are both integers, then there are not many ways to make sure that $a^2+2b^2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2+2b^2=1 \Rightarrow 2b^2=1-a^2=(1-a)(1+a)$

$2b^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow -1 \leq a \leq 1$

but we know the fact that $a$ is an integer so

$ -1 \leq a \leq 1 $ and $a \in \Bbb Z \Rightarrow $ $a=-1$ or  $a=1$ or $a=0$

let $a=0$ then

$2b^2=1$  which does not have an integer solution so $a \neq 0$

$a=1$ , $b=0$

$a=-1$ , $b=0$ are only solutions

Comment: If $-1\le a\le 1$ then $a=0$ seems to be a solution.  A complete answer proves that possibility wrong.

Comment: thx i fixed it.